# why Spark is not distributing jobs to all executors, but to only one executer?

Tags: performance, configuration, apache-spark, distributed-computing, spark-streaming

My Spark cluster has 1 master and 3 workers (on 4 separate machines, each machine with 1 core), and other settings are as in the picture below, where **spark.cores.max** is set to **3**, and **spark.executor.cores** also **3** (in **pic-1**)

But when I submit my job to Spark cluster, from the Spark web-UI I can see only one executor is used (according to **used memory** and **RDD blocks** in **pic-2**), but not all of the executors. In this case the processing speed is much slower than I expected.

Since I've set the max cores to be 3, shouldn't all the executors be used to this job?

How to configurate Spark to distribute current job to all executors, instead of only one executor running current job?

Thanks a lot.

**------------------pic-1**:
[image: spark settings]

**------------------pic-2**:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you are running two receivers, what kind of Receivers are they (Kafka, Hdfs, Twitter ??)

Which spark version are you using?

In my experience, if you are using any Receiver other than file receiver, then it will occupy 1 core permanently.
So when you say you have 2 receivers, then 2 cores will be permanently used for receiving the data, so you are left with only 1 core which is doing the work.

Please post the Spark master hompage screenshot as well. And Job's Streaming page screenshot.

Comment: for the kind of Receivers, I'm not sure, just using the default one after downloading Spark 1.3 package. It should be Kafka.

Comment: I'm streaming from AWS Kinesis to Spark, my guess is this receiver is corresponding the Kinesis shards, since I have 2 shards for my Kinesis stream.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of Spark master streaming page. docs "When running a Spark Streaming program locally, do not use “local” or “local[1]” as the master URL. Either of these means that only one thread will be used for running tasks locally. If you are using a input DStream based on a receiver (e.g. sockets, Kafka, Flume, etc.), then the single thread will be used to run the receiver, leaving no thread for processing the received data. Hence, when running locally, always use “local[n]” as the master URL where n > number of receivers to run" The above applied for cluster as well.

Comment: actually,  I do know that “local[n]” where n is the number of threads. but this is only for one machine mode. I have a cluster of 4 machines and then master-ip-address should be used instead of “local[n]”, so it does not apply to my situation. thanks anyway

Comment: I am aware that you have a cluster, but what I have said applies for cluster with more than 1 machine as well refer the spark documentation and programming guide ... I am helping you because I faced this issue with 3 server cluster and it took me 2 days to make my job run on three executors.

Comment: thank you Lokesh. when you say "local[n]", where do you put it? as I understand, in spark conf file you specify the spark-master-address to be either "local[n]" or "spark://[master-node-ip]:[port]". so for a cluster you cannot use "local[n]", is it right?

Comment: Hi the point is not about local[n] the point is about 'n' which is number of cores you allocate to your job, it may be single system or cluster, I was just asking about the number of cores you assigned and number of cores that are free for processing your jobs. As mentioned in prev comments please post the snapshots so that we will get better idea of your setup.

Comment: hi @lokesh-kumar-p, sorry for this late reply. and I tried your idea out, and you are right, it's related to the receivers. thanks a lot :P

Answer (score 1):

In spark streaming only 1 receiver is launched, to get the data from input source to RDD.

Repartitioning the data after the 1st transformation can increase parallelism.

Comment: Hi I have 2 receivers launched. And could you please give an example of how to Repartitioning?